# Count occurences in a mongo record during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is a playground I've done to ease the finding of the answer https://mongoplayground.net/p/rthdTzpHkZ1

I have a collection of items

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("611ba6d26aaaf2446f7fc45e"),
    "hashtags": [
      "test1",
      "test2"
    ],
    "hour": ISODate("2021-08-16T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "username": "username1",
    "lang": "fr",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("611ba6d26aaaf2446f7fc45f"),
    "hashtags": [
      "test1"
    ],
    "hour": ISODate("2021-08-09T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "lang": "fr",
    "username": "username1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("611ba6d26aaaf2446f7fc460"),
    "hashtags": [
      "test2",
      "test3"
    ],
    "hour": ISODate("2021-08-16T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "lang": "en",
    "username": "username2"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("611ba6d26aaaf2446f7fc462"),
    "hashtags": [
      "test2",
      "test3"
    ],
    "hour": ISODate("2021-08-16T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "lang": "en",
    "username": "username2"
  }
]
```

And want to

- group them by `hour`
- get an object of each `hashtag`, `lang` and `username` as keys along with the number of times they appeared
- sort those `hashtag`, `lang` and `username` alphabetically

like so

```
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "hour": ISODate("2021-08-16T04:00:00Z")
      },
      "hashtags": {
          "test1": 1,
          "test2": 3,
          "test3": 2
      },
      "languages": {
        "en": 2,
        "fr": 1
        
      },
      "usernames": {
        "username1": 1,
        "username2": 2
      },
      "nbLikes": 0,
      "nbQuotes": 0,
      "nbRetweets": 0,
      "nbTweets": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "hour": ISODate("2021-08-09T04:00:00Z")
      },
      "hashtags": {
        "test1": 1
      },
      "languages": {
        "fr": 1
      },
      "usernames": {
        "username1": 1
      },
      "nbLikes": 0,
      "nbQuotes": 0,
      "nbRetweets": 0,
      "nbTweets": 1
    }
  ]
```

The closest I got is in the playground here https://mongoplayground.net/p/rthdTzpHkZ1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to use the [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator to create a dicctionary with `language`, `hashtags` and `username` as keys.

### Explanation

```
                   $map + $reduce
["en", "fr", "en"] ---------------> [{k:"en", v:2}, {k:"fr", v:1}, {k:"en", v:2}]
                                              
[{k:"en", v:2},    $arrayToObject
 {k:"fr", v:1},    ---------------> {"en":2, "fr":1}
 {k:"en", v:2}]
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "hour": "$hour"
      },
      "nbTweets": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "nbRetweets": {
        "$sum": "$retweetCount"
      },
      "nbQuotes": {
        "$sum": "$retweetCount"
      },
      "nbLikes": {
        "$sum": "$likeCount"
      },
      usernames: {
        "$push": "$username"
      },
      hashtags: {
        "$push": "$hashtags"
      },
      languages: {
        "$push": "$lang"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      hashtags: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$hashtags",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "languages": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$languages",
              as: "lang",
              in: {
                k: "$$lang",
                v: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$languages",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$lang",
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "hashtags": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$hashtags",
              as: "hash",
              in: {
                k: "$$hash",
                v: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$hashtags",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$hash",
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "usernames": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$usernames",
              as: "user",
              in: {
                k: "$$user",
                v: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$usernames",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$user",
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id.hour": -1
    },
    
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/24XlQAkWre_)